# TypeError: (0 , _pages_auth__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.registerUser) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My Auth.js file

```
const registerStudent = async (formData) => {
  const { address ,batchTime, collageName, email, fatherName, gender, guardianMobile, hscBoard, hscGPA, hscPassingYear,
    hscReg, hscRoll, imgeURL, motherName, name, paymentAmount, programName, schoolName, sscBoard, sscGPA, sscPassingYear,
    sscReg, sscRoll, studentMobile, transactionID } = formData;

  console.log(address);
  return address;
}
```

I am importing this function from other file like below

```
import { registerUser }  from '../../api/auth';
```

But getting warning

> Cannot resolve symbol 'registerUser'

> Create class 'registerUser'

After trying to execute the function I am getting the error. I am using nextjs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the function and rename it

```
export const registerUser = async (formData) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your function as registerStudent and you are exporting it as registerUser, that's why it's giving you that error

```
import { registerUser }  from '../../api/auth';
```

So in Auth.js export your function like this

```
export const registerStudent = async (formData) => {}
```

and import it like this,

```
import { registerStudent }  from '../../api/auth';
```